# Bucket names not being appended to a list

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, amazon-s3, logic, boto3

I'm trying to append to the **public_buckets** list all the bucket names of buckets that have BlockPublicAcls and BlockPublicPolicy set to False. For this, I'm using a counter that means the bucket is public when it is equal to 2.

```
filtered_buckets = list(filter(lambda item: not list_in_list(exceptions, item['Name']), buckets))
public_buckets = []

def check_bucket_access_block():
    for bucket in filtered_buckets:
        try:
            response = s3client.get_public_access_block(Bucket=bucket['Name'])
            for key, value in response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration'].items():
                logger.info('Bucket: {}, {}: {}'.format(bucket['Name'], key, value))
                count = 0
                if key == response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration']['BlockPublicAcls'] and value == False:
                    count += 1
                if key == response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration']['BlockPublicPolicy'] and value == False:
                    count += 1
                if count == 2 and bucket['Name'] not in public_buckets:
                    public_buckets.append(bucket['Name'])
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchPublicAccessBlockConfiguration':
                print("Bucket: {} has no Public Access Block Configuration".format(bucket['Name']))
            else:
                print("unexpected error: %s" % (e.response))
```

I know there are a few buckets in the **filtered_buckets** list with both key values set to False. However, they are not being appended to the list.

When I print the **public_buckets** list it returns an empty **[]**.

This is the **response** syntax:

```
{
    'PublicAccessBlockConfiguration': {
        'BlockPublicAcls': True|False,
        'IgnorePublicAcls': True|False,
        'BlockPublicPolicy': True|False,
        'RestrictPublicBuckets': True|False
    }
}
```

I don't know if that's a logical mistake - in the if statements - or maybe a type mismatch.

Any idea?

Comment: What are the `key, value` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic in this line isn't doing what you expect:

```
if key == response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration']['BlockPublicAcls'] and value == False:
```

`response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration']['BlockPublicAcls']` will return `True` or `False` -- it's returning the `Value` for that dictionary entry, not the `Key`.

Instead, you could use:

```py
if not response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration']['BlockPublicAcls'] and not response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration']['BlockPublicPolicy'] and bucket['Name'] not in public_buckets:
    public_buckets.append(bucket['Name'])
```

This will append the bucket name if `BlockPublicAcls` and `BlockPublicAcls` are both False and the bucket is not already in the list.